# How can I get the len of nontype

Tags: python

Hello guys I'm trying to write a program that generate a random password then cracks is it but I'm getting the error object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```py
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase 

def nrndprint(n):
  k=(''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(n)))  #.join
  print(k)
nrndprint(6)
```

```
import itertools
def crack_pass(argpass):
  alplist = list(map(chr,list(range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))))
  for combi in itertools.product(alplist,repeat=len(argpass)):
    if "".join(combi)==argpass:
      return combi
  return '-1'
passwd = nrndprint(4)
print(passwd)
print(crack_pass(passwd))
```

I'm getting:

```
#mqjz
#None
```

Expected:

```
#mqjz
#('m','q','j','z')
```

Comment: To answer your question: You can't. What would you expect length of *nothing* to be? To solve your problem: your `nrndprint(4)` doesn't return any value, so passwd gets assigned `None`.

Comment: You can't; you have to avoid calling `len` on `None` in the first place. You do that by not confusing `print` with `return`.

Comment: I think it's better instead of cracking password by writing function. Just download  100000 common password file in CSV and then write function to compare the given password value and given value in CSV. It's what most pen-tester uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't calculate the length of `NoneType`.

Your function `nrndprint()` doesn't return anything. Adding `return k` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

NoneType doesn't have `len()` method so it's raising an error.

You are assinging `passwd = nrndprint(4)` and then passing the `passwd` variable to `crack_pass`, but since your function `nrndprint` doesn't return anything, variable `passwd` will be `None`. You can fix it by making `nrndprint` function return a value.